# Android animating material motion

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I have been trying to achieve the effect of this animation for hours now and just can't get it right:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s400/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif

http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this and perhaps post some code?

Edit:

Its not the shared element transition I'm trying to achieve, its the smooth dropdown of the text and smooth expanding of the status bar. I have tried animating scale with different interpolators but I cant make it feel right

Comment: Search for "Shared Element Transition in Android"